# Linux Kernel Driver for video capture

Tags: drivers, linux-mint, kernel, video-capture

I have this EasyCap video capture thing with a USBTV007 chip and I really would like to get it working on my little linux mint 17 laptop so that I can capture video for my RC stuff.

But I do not know what to do with this linux kernel driver. I don't even know how to get these files, I assume it is something like git.
http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Easycap#USBTV007_EasyCAP

I am looking for a beginner friendly explanation on what to do with this: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/media/usb/usbtv

Answer (score 1):

On current market various identical model of Easy Cap video capture device with a USBTV007 chip inside is available with different Vendor/Product ID stamped inside USB Device ID. So before going to compile other driver insted of using built-in 'usbtv' modules comes with linux image package by default. 
Issue command bellow on a terminal

```
>sudo lsusb
```

You would probably get something like:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d71:3002 USB TV
```

Look for ID **1d71:3002** somewhere within output of lsusb command, if matchd, you are lucky, your system might have driver for your device. If not, don't be hopeless. Lets see what unique ID you have?

```
ID eb1a:2861 eMPIA Technology, Inc.
ID 1c88:0007 Somagic, Inc. 
ID 1c88:003c Somagic, Inc. 
ID 1c88:003f Somagic, Inc.
```

Any of above four ID match will have other deferent driver already available by default with your kernel release. Please read carefully on Linux TV page you mention.

I used to have very uncommon and newly released device (as far my knowledge from market source)

```
ID 1d71:3002 USB TV
```

What it needed was adding single line on usbtv driver souce file name usbtv-core.c and recompiling it on fly. 
To do so you need to have usbtv source code with various component of v4l linux project. I would recommend you to download and work with full kernel source on hand but only recompiling module source after adding single line for adding your device ID on driver base. I am giving bellow step by step command. I am ignoring description of steps for quick finish. Let me know if it give you hard time understand. I will edit to add details later.

Install all utility and application and library file for Linux Kernel Compile process. Few of package are

make, gcc, autoconf, binutils, build-essential ,  libncurses-dev along with headers file of your kernel.

After having all necessasry package installed, try :

```
>cd /usr/src/linux-source-X.XX.X
>sudo cp /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/Module.symvers .
>sudo make -C  /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/ oldconfig
>sudo cp /boot/config-X.xx.x-xx-YYYY .config
>sudo make -C  /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/ prepare
```

If above steps are completed without any error, congratulation. Hard time are over. Now move to usbtv source file by:

```
cd /usr/src/linux-source-X.XX.X/drivers/media/usb/usbtv/
```

There you will find files name: 
    Kconfig  Makefile  usbtv-audio.c  usbtv-core.c  usbtv.h  usbtv-video.c

Open usbtv-core.c file for modification with your favorite text editor and modify code having:

```
static struct usb_device_id usbtv_id_table[] = {
{ USB_DEVICE(0x1b71, 0x3002) },
{}
```

};

With code showing bellow.

```
static struct usb_device_id usbtv_id_table[] = {
{ USB_DEVICE(0x1b71, 0x3002) },
{ USB_DEVICE(0x1f71, 0x3301) },
{}
```

};

With line 0x1f71 as vendor id and 0x3301 as product ID you are instructing your driver to load as soon any device with matching ID tag inserted on USB port. Try changing other Product/Vendor ID if you sure of UTV007 chip set on your device. Point is to have your own product/vendor ID match with drivers one. Now try compiling modules by:

```
>sudo make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/ M=$PWD prepare modules install 
>sudo depmod -a
```

If this point finish without error, unload/reload usbtv module with command

```
>sudo rmmod usbtv && sudo modprobe usbtv
```

while connecting your device on USB port try monitoring UDEV activity with command

```
 > udevadm monitor
```

Showing /dev/vedio0 drive just after inserting your device will result of success. If not let us know for further discussion.

Additional Source:

https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Gadmei_USB_TVBox_UTV382_(id_0x1f71:0x3301)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/168279/how-do-i-build-a-single-in-tree-kernel-module
https://askubuntu.com/questions/17944/what-is-the-minimum-requirement-to-compile-kernel-modules

To sign your modified module with self signed certificate :

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-signing-kernel-modules-for-secure-boot.html

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this:

```
p=`pwd`
git clone https://github.com/simon3z/usbtv.git
cd usbtv/
cd /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`
make  SUBDIRS=/root/usbtv  modules
cd /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`
cd /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/media/usb/usbtv/
cp $p/usbtv/usbtv.ko .
```